# Why is process state volatile?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

In linux, `struct task_struct::state` has the type `volatile unsigned long` for a long time. I used to think as long as there are spin lock (or something else) to protect a data structure, then `volatile` shouldn't be used. I wonder why it is here.

In [here](https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/memory_barriers.html) Linus Torvalds gave an explanation of how to use `volatile`:

> the thread flag could be marked volatile, but that would just make the ordering 'invisible' . And the fact is, the ordering is really between those *two* data structures - it's not just one of them that is somehow magically 'volatile'.

The example he made is that we need to access `preem_count` and `thread flag` in order, we could use `volatile` on `thread flag`, but the best way is using `barrier` between two accessing because `volatile` is kind of implicit.

This problem is solved by Chris Dodd's comment, and `volatile` here is to get (or let the others get) fresh state in case interrupt has changed (or want to read) that. So I think the idea here is since process state can be used without spin lock protected, kernel just use a big hammer here to make it `volatile`. For example, kernel would set process state to `TASK_UNINTERRUPT` to tell interrupt handler "I've already waited for something so leave me alone".

Comment: spinlock/atomic/memory barrier is a signal for CPU to stop reordering memory writes. volatile is for compiler to not cache a value in a register+stop reordering compiled instructions. They are independent.

Comment: `volatile` forces the compiler to read it before every use and store after every change.

Comment: Bare in mind that you read 20y old comments.

Comment: In general, a kernel is going to use `volatile` on things that might be modified by an interrupt handler, since the interrupt might trigger anywhere.

Comment: After the `volatile long state;` member was changed to `unsigned int __state;` it was only accessed via a `volatile unsigned int *`, so is still effectively volatile. I think this was just part of some general cleanup to use the `READ_ONCE(x)`/`WRITE_ONCE(x, val)` macros.